# RSA keypair "diversification"?

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa

Symmetric keys (AES, 3DES, ...) can be diversified by a specified diversification input. It is usually done this way:

```
DivKey = Enc[PlainText = Key, IV = DivInput, K = Key]
```

However, this is based on the fact that each 16-byte array is a valid AES key.

Is there any way do something similar with whole RSA keypairs? I would like to provide a different RSA private key to each of my "clients", but I would like to keep just one RSA public key to be able to verify their signatures. If there were a diversification algorithm for whole RSA keypairs, I could give my clients a "diversified" private key and keep the original public key to verify all their signatures. This is important for me, because I need to store the public key in a device with very limited persistent memory.

Is there such an algorithm? If yes, is there any Java libary implementing it?

Maybe it is obvious that such a diversification algorithm cannot exist, I really do not know.

If you think this question should be moved to cryptoexchange, do so, please.

Comment: Every private key has a corresponding public key and vise versa. So you can not use any _diversification_ for any kind of key pair.

Comment: @rakeb.void I know, but I thought there might be an algorithm, which transforms the whole keypair to another valid keypair...

Comment: Then what? Your requirement is not going to fulfill, because if the whole key pair is changed then you will get another brand new unique public and private key! For symmetric key, key diversification works as the process is same for both end. But for public key concept, every user must have a unique public key.

Comment: @rakeb.void Of course, but because the algorithm and the original keypair is known to me, I could dynamically transform the public key to "diversified" public key in the moment I need to verify a signature created by one of the "diversified" private keys. Exactly the same mechanism works fine with AES keys.

Comment: Ok, let make it clear. Suppose you have a key-pair  `kp` consist of public key `pk` and private key `prk`. Before we penetrate further we both agree that `pk` differs from `prk`. Now for symmetric key, say a master key `mk` is diversified as `mk1`, `mk2` and `mk3` by mechanism `alg`. Now entity `A` has `mk` so using `alg` he can generate any of `mk1`, `mk2` or `mk3`. Say another entity `B`, he also has `mk` as well as `alg`. So `B` can also generate any of `mk1`, `mk2` or `mk3` using `alg`. Hence they communicate.

Comment: But as like `mk`, `A` and `B` don't have same `pk` or `prk` although they have same `alg`, so they can't communicate like how they communicate via symmetric diversified key!

Comment: My "vision": entity A has `pk` from key-pair `kp`. An `alg` could be used to create `pk1`, `prk1`, `pk2`, `prk2`, `pk3`, `prk3` ... Entity E1 has `prk1`, entity E2 has `prk2` etc. That is how entity E2 can create a different signature than E1, but A can verify all their signatures with the same public key `pk` and algorithm `alg`.

Comment: The `alg` you are mentioned is just like `Key Pair` generation algorithm! Please, note that, any number can be used as symmetric key, but not any two different number can act as public-private key pair! Moreover, a public key must be certified to use. :v

Comment: @rakeb.void That is what the question is all about! `alg` must create a valid key-pair from a valid key-pair.

Comment: This might be an XY problem. There is no such thing for RSA, but a similar thing can be achieved. Can you describe what your use case is? Is it simply that you don't want to store the public key, but generate them on the fly?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I need to store the public key in a device with a very limited persistent memory. Hence each byte is important for me. Yes, I would like to generate the derived public keys on the fly. DSA would be fine, too. ECDSA not, my chip does not support it effectively.

Comment: @vojta, I've no idea why you need to store public key in a limited precious memory where the key itself _public_!

Comment: @rakeb.void Because the device is the only trusted environment. It receives signed commands sent by clients, verifies them and executes them.

Comment: @vojta If entity *A* generates the key pairs for all participants *E_i* and verifies the signatures itself, then there is no need for RSA, because the public keys aren't actually made public (they stay at entity *A*). Simply use HMAC with a symmetric key with your "diversification" scheme. If the keys, will be made public beside entity *A*, does *A* generate the key pairs itself or do the participants generate their key pairs and just sent their public keys to *A*?

Comment: @ArtjomB. In real world there are many entities A. There is a master server M, which generates a keypair for each participant. It uploads the private key under protected conditions into the participant's secure token and uploads the public key into all "verifying entities" A_i (these are the devices with limited memory). If there is a keypair for each participant, it could be generated in the secure token, of course. Thanks, I will try to implement your HMAC solution, it seems to be the optimal way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of thing is hard to generate for RSA. The public key cannot be created separately from the private key. The private key would have to be generated from the other private key but there isn't a clear mathematical connection between the master private key material and the generated one.

Not that it is needed. What you can do is simply generate a key pair on the client. Then send a certificate request from the client to the server. The server will return a certificate signed by a private key of a *trusted* certificate. Now if the client wants to connect it send this certificate. The server will verify that it was signed by the trusted certificate. After that it has a trusted public key of the client.

In other words, read into X509 based PKI to understand why such an key derivation method is not required.

Comment: Cleaned up the text to make it easier to understand. Please indicate if anything is still missing...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate the client private keys yourself (and distribute them to your clients somehow), you can easily stay with symmetric cryptography (IMHO asymmetric cryptography does not offer any advantage for such use case, if your validating device is trusted enough to keep the MK).

Technically it should be possible to generate diversified RSA keypairs by seeding a random number generator used to generate the keypair with a known (secret, generated-from-client-id, long-enough, hard-to-predict...) value unique for each client. Then you can re-generate any keypair by repeating the key generation process using the same value (see e.g. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1665/25845). **I strongly do not recommend to do this**).

As Maarten Bodewes says, PKI is the perfect solution for your problem if you want to stay with RSA. Please note, that X509 is not the only way how to implement PKI.

It is also worth mentioning, that for the simplest use cases with PKI, you do not need any secure validation device -- the validation can be performed in untrusted zone (which is probably not your use case).

Desclaimer: I am no crypto expert, so please do validate my thoughts.